# AngularJS ui-router prevent anchor redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a multi-step form in my app.
The routing is done using UI-Router states.

in the multi-step form, the changes between views made by anchor tags. for example:

```
        <a ui-sref="post_add.social" class="btn btn-orange" ng-class="{disabled: addItem_form.$invalid && !AddItem.CondoIsChoosen}" ng-click="locationCheck(AddItem.condo_address, AddItem.choosenCondo)">
            Continue <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>
        </a>
```

On location check, i have an additional check to verify current step's data.

**The problem is** - no matter the result of `locationCheck()`, `ui-sref` making redirect to the next view. How can i prevent it?

disabling the element itself is not suit for this case.

Comment: Setup state change inside your ng-click and remove ui-sref

Comment: ops. exaclty. thanks, blind me:D